# Is there any benefit to having more farmland?

Tags: anno-1404

When you build farms like a Hemp Farm you need to build farmland around it with different arms needing a different number of farmlands to reach 100% productivity ie.

- Hemp = 4
- Goat Milk = 3
- Dates = 5

But if i had the space to build more that what was required, do i get any bonus for it? when i had hemp farms with 5-6 farmlands i only ever see the productivity at 100% (where you see how many farms you need)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is (to my knowledge) no benefit in any of the anno games to build more farmlands than what is required for 100% productivity.